# Error in javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, debugging, jhipster

I am trying to build my Jhipster Spring boot application in maven. However, Maven is not building in the debug mode. Otherwise, it is working fine.

I have added following dependency, didn't help.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

```
Description:

An attempt was made to call the method javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()Ljavax/persistence/SynchronizationType; but it does not exist. Its class, javax.persistence.PersistenceContext, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/User/Documents/audio-book-admin/lib/javax.persistence.jar!/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.2.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.2.Final.jar!/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/javax/persistence/persistence-api/1.0/persistence-api-1.0.jar!/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Users/User/Documents/audio-book-admin/lib/javax.persistence.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.persistence.PersistenceContext
```

So, How can I properly correct classpath of my application to reslove  the above issues? I am new in Spring boot!

Comment: What is this folder C:/Users/User/Documents/audio-book-admin/lib/ ? Did you add it to your JHipster project ?

Answer (score 1):

First remove in your repository maven the directory hibernate and then make a 
*maven clean install* to re import correctly your dependencies.

if it still doesn't fix your problem make a *maven tree:dependency* to detect what dependence is causing issue  and exclude it in your pom